# OpenSubtab in the component which is opened from VF page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, subtab-apps

I am trying to open a subtab from the lightning which is invoked from vf page.

Sceanrio: I have invoked component A from  VF page(page1), in the component A i have placed a lightning button which needs to invoke VF page(page2) with some parameters. But when i am clicking on the lightning button, it is not redirecting to VF page. Can someone please help me. Here is my code.

VF Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//get account Id from URL
var accountId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}";
//Create Lightning Component
$Lightning.use("c:CXT_ViewAllAttributes", function() {
    $Lightning.createComponent("c:CXT_ViewAllAttributesComp", 
                                { "accountId" : accountId },
                               "LightningContainer", function(component) {
                                   console.log('Component created');
                               });
});
</script>
```

Lightning App:

```
<!--Attributes App-->
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="global">
    <!--Lightning component-->
    <aura:dependency resource="c:CXT_ViewAllAttributesComp"/>
</aura:application>
```

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component controller="CXT_NBOAttributesController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <!--Declare Attributes-->
    <aura:attribute name="attLstNBO" type="object[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="accountId" type="Id" />
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>
    <aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object"/>
    <!--Declare Handlers-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <div>
        <p>  </p>
        <p>  </p>
        <p>  </p>
        <p>  </p>
        <p>  </p>
        <p>  </p>
    </div>
    <div style="color:#616265;font-weight:700;background:#F3F2F2;PADDING-LEFT:15PX;font-size:15px;">
        <div style="color:#616265;font-weight:700;background:#F3F2F2;PADDING-LEFT:15PX;font-size:15px;">Next Best Offers</div>
        <table style="box-sizing: border-box;border: 1px solid #ACB8BF;border-color: #8D363B;margin: 10px;border-radius: 5px;float: left;overflow: hidden;background-color: #F4F6F9;display: inline-block;min-height: 175px; width:30%" >
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.attLstNBO}" var="item" indexVar="index">
            <tr>
           <td>
               <lightning:icon iconName="standard:loop" size="small" alternativeText="Event" aria-describedby="help" /> 
                    <!-- <lightning:helptext content="{!item.hText}"/> -->
           </td>
           <td>
               <p> <b> <lightning:button variant="base" label="{!item.nboattr}" onclick="{!c.handleClickvwall}" value="{!index}" /> </b> <br/>
                   Address: {!item.address} <br/>
                            {!item.addrCtyState}<br/>
                   ESIID : {!item.esiid}<br/>
                   Expiration Date : {!item.expDate}
               </p>
           </td> 
            </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
      </table>  
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Lightning Component controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var accountId = component.get("v.accountId");
        var action = component.get("c.getAttributes");
        action.setParams({
            "recId": accountId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            var result = a.getReturnValue();    
            component.set("v.attLstNBO", result);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);  
    },
    handleClickvwall : function(component, event, helper) {
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        var recId = component.get("v.accountId");
        var idx = event.getSource().get('v.value');
        var esi = component.get("v.attLstNBO")[idx].esiid;
        workspaceAPI.getEnclosingTabId({
        }).then(function(enclosingTabId) {
            workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
                parentTabId: enclosingTabId,
                url: '/apex/CXT_UniversalOmniScriptPage?id={0}&OmniScriptType=Sales&OmniScriptSubType=ServicePlanChange&OmniScriptLang=English&PrefillDataRaptorBundle=&scriptMode=vertical&layout=lightning&ContextId={0}&ESIID='+ esi,
                focus: true
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: You are using this in console apps right  if you are did you tried printing enclosingTabId in that function were you getting any value there?

Comment: It is getting as undefined..

Comment: did you used workspace.getFocusedTabInfo() instead of enclosingtabid maybe it can work.